# Fixing creation time to be = modified time

Tags: windows, file-management

Somehow, all my mp3 and jpg images on my backup network drive are fine, but my local computer has the creation time BIGGER then the modified time (modified time is the right one).

Now, every time I want to create backup (using robocopy) it copies everything because he thinks the files are newer!

How do I fix all the local files to have Creation time = Modified time ?

OS: Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Is this on VMS or OS/400?

Comment: @Dennis There's only one OS that does Robocopy, so it's quite obviously OS3.1.

Comment: updated: Win 7 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

[See this article](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-the-last-modified-date-creation-date-and-last-accessed-date-for-files-and-folders/):

> Changing the date on a file is actually quite complicated if you try to do it yourself, but thankfully there are a few really nice freeware applications that can get the job done for you quickly and easily. I’m going to quickly go through three different apps each that do pretty much the same thing, but I’d rather mention more than less just in case one does not work for you.

Comment: none of those apps lets you do what I want (creation = modified) as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd problem, I thought Robocopy used the modified date. The dates are like that because the creation time is the time **that** version of the file was created. So if you create a file, modify it and then copy it an hour later, that new copy will have a modified date 1 hour earlier than the creation date.

There is a CLI app called [DirDate](http://www.datamystic.com/dirdate.html) that can do this, it has a 30 day trial. You will need to script it to loop through each file individually though as the reference date must be hardcoded on the command line.